# Factors of a number in an array (PHP function)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm probably missing something simple here, but I have this function for finding the factors of a number.

```
 function factor($n){
 $factors_array = array();
 for ($x = 1; $x <= sqrt(abs($n)); $x++)
 {
    if ($n % $x == 0)
    {
        $z = $n/$x; 
        array_push($factors_array, $x, $z);
       }
   }
   return $factors_array;
 }
```

I then want to do something like this...

```
factor(120);
print_r($factors_array);
```

This give me nothing though.  Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning the variable to the return value of the function. As far as the PHP interpreter is concerned, `$factors_array` only exists if you're *inside* the `factor()` function. Try this:

```
$factors_array = factor(120);
print_r($factors_array);
```

Then you can reuse `$factors_array` in other areas of the code.

Have a look at [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for an explanation of why this happens.

Comment: I do need this to be used in other areas of the code, so this works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
print_r(factor(120));
```

Because you can't access $factors_array; outside the function, this is called scope of variable, usually, variables that defined inside function are not available outside, also, variables that are defined outside function are not available inside function...

Read more [Variable scope ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)